# put the result of a query into a variable and WITH statement

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I need to put the result of a query into a variable.

Just a query, works as successful

```
DECLARE @count INT = (

SELECT count (*)
FROM [AdventureWorks].[Person].[Address]    
);

select @count;
```

But if I need to use the `WITH` statement in a query, then I get a syntax error

```
DECLARE @count INT = (
   WITH person_address (id)
   as (
    SELECT AddressID
    FROM [AdventureWorks].[Person].[Address]
   )
   SELECT count (*)
   FROM person_address    
);

select @count;
```

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WITH'.

> Msg 319, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'. If this statement is a common table expression, an xmlnamespaces clause or a change tracking context clause, the previous statement must be terminated with a semicolon.

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 9
> Incorrect syntax near ')'.

How do I put the query value into a variable if the `WITH` clause is used in the SQL statement?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assign the variable in the last query.

```
DECLARE @count INT;

WITH person_address (id)
as (
    SELECT AddressID
    FROM [AdventureWorks].[Person].[Address]
   )
   SELECT @count = count (*)
   FROM person_address;

select @count;
```

```
create table t (id int);

insert into t values
(1),(1),(2),(1),(2);

declare @cnt int;

with ct as
(
    select id from t
)
select
  @cnt = count(*)
from
  ct
where id = 1;

select @cnt;
```

> ```
> | (No column name) |
> | ---------------: |
> |                3 |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=98c9cb3d880f9a08bf39039313415c9c)*

Comment: @IvanGusev Note the reasoning for this is because a **CTE** (the `WITH` clause) needs to be the first in the batch (per the SQL Server spec). Normally you can prefix the `WITH` clause with a semicolon `;` to terminate the previous batch, but in your case that wouldn't work with syntax you were trying to use. Instead this answer re-writes your syntax so that the variable is declared first and that batch is terminated with a semicolon, then the **CTE** is defined and finally the variable is set to the result of the **CTE** and selected.